# access Master page in class file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, master-pages

I have got the following contents in Master Page:

```
<ul>
    <li id="link1" runat="server"><a href="mytestfile.aspx">Test Files</a></li>
    <li id="link2" runat="server"><a href="mylistitemtest.aspx">List Item Test</a></li>
    <li id="link3" runat="server"><a href="Mytest2.aspx">Some Test</a></li>    
</ul>
```

I have a class called `data_class.cs` and i have created the following method in this class to disable controls on the Master Page:

```
public static void disablecontrol()
{
    Master.FindControl("link1").Visible = false;
    Master.FindControl("Link3").Visible = false;
}
```

I am getting the following error on Using "Master" word.

`an object reference is Required for non-staticfield, method, property 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage.master.get'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this :

```
var pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
if (pageHandler  is  System.Web.UI.Page)
{
  ((System.Web.UI.Page)pageHandler).Master.FindControl("...").Visible=false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `aspx` file add the following directive:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="YorNamespace.YourMasterClass" %>
```

Create a method exposing your method in the `MasterPage`:

```
public void disablecontrol()
{
    Master.Link1.Visible = false;
    Master.Link3.Visible = false;
}
```

And in your `aspx.cs` file you can simple:

```
this.Master.disablecontrol();
```

Edit: It will change your `aspx.designer` file making the cast for you in the `this.Master` property as following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Master property.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Auto-generated property.
/// </remarks>
public new YorNamespace.YourMasterClass Master {
    get {
        return ((YorNamespace.YourMasterClass)(base.Master));
    }
}
```

More about [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228274%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Because this method is static, it doesn't have access to the [properties of the page object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Run this code in an instance method of the page.